# Cookie is sent by server but it is not being stored on the browser

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, jwt

the server sends the set-cookie header successfully but it is not being stored or sent by the browser.

the reactjs front-end is running on a different server than the front-backend
and I don't know why it is not working. this is the cookie in the browser when it is being sent

[image]

Comment: Try to store it in indexDB of browser

Comment: "running on a different server" ... a server sets cookies only for its own domain, and the browser will only send it back to that same domain.

Comment: Also the browser has tools to examine cookies from each domain. Are you saying that your "onrender.com" domain has no cookies set in the browser?

Comment: i am specifying the domain  of the cookie why isn't that working

Comment: Again, a server response can only set cookies for its own domain.\

Comment: so what is the use of the domain option

Comment: If you have "something.yourcompany.com", you can set the domain to "yourcompany.com". The rules for that are complicated.

Comment: aha i got you now , so what do you suggest to solve this issue ?